# How to pass access token for subscribe in youtube v3 data api

Tags: youtube

How to pass access token in this url for subscribe 
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Answer (score 0):

Hope, this will help you.

- First you need to get an authorization from the user.

[How to use the Youtube api for subscriptions](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/insert#part) and 
[To find your youtube channel ID](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/3250431?hl=en)

Once you have got the authorization from the user whom you want to subscribe to your list.

Then your request should (used from googleapi site)
`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet
     {
 "snippet": {
  "resourceId": {
   "channelId": "YOUR CHANNEL ID"
  }
 }
}`

ChannelId of yours whom the user wants to subscribe.
You should choose the program where you want to use the api.

> URL occurs as 
>   https://www.content.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet&key={Base64 of your authorized code}&alt=json